# What is the person who records the sales/winning bids in an Auction called?

Tags: nouns, synonyms

In an auction there is a person doing the auction chant (auctioneer) and another person recording the results : who won and for how much.

What is that second person called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the auctions

> **clerk**
>
> The person employed by the principal auctioneer or auction firm to record what is sold, to whom and for what price.
>
> [liveauctioneers.com: terminology](https://www.liveauctioneers.com/terminology.html)

Here's a more complete

> job description:
>
> 1) Records amounts of final bids for merchandise at auction sales, and receives money from final bidders at auction: Locates lot and item number of article up for bidding on record sheet.
>
> 2) Listens to amount of bids called for by AUCTIONEER and records final amount bid for article.
>
> 3) Receives deposit money or full payment from final bidders.
>
> [careerplanner.com: AUCTION-CLERK](http://dot-job-descriptions.careerplanner.com/AUCTION-CLERK.cfm)